# WHY as.POSIXct(Date&time) in R will lose my time?

Tags: r, posixct

I am using the dataset whcih has date and time variables like this: Date Time 2006-12-16  17:24:00 ... for thousands of rows.
and what I want is to create POSIXct format of date& time.
here is my code:

```
data_full <-read.csv("C:/R/household_power_consumption/household_power_consumption.txt",
                 header= T,sep = ';',na.strings = "?", 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data_full$Date <- as.Date(data_full$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
datetime <- paste(as.Date(data_full$Date), data_full$Time)
##head(datetime)
data_full$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime)
##head(data_full$Datetime)
```

however, the Datetime variable only contain dates,not time.

```
head(data_full$Datetime)
[1] "2006-12-16 EST" "2006-12-16 EST" "2006-12-16 EST" "2006-12-16 EST" 
"2006-12-16 EST" "2006-12-16 EST"
```

but the datetime variable contains both date and times, so I think it might be the trouble of as.POSIXct.

```
head(datetime)
[1] "2006-12-16 17:24:00" "2006-12-16 17:25:00" "2006-12-16 17:26:00" "2006-12-16 17:27:00" "2006-12-16 17:28:00"
[6] "2006-12-16 17:29:00"
```

So does anyone get the idea what happened? I am so confused....
Thanks for help!

Comment: To test @RichScriven hypothesis, try `which(!grepl("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$", datetime))`. Will return the vector positions that don't match `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format.

Comment: The problem is that you do not provide a reproducible example. If I try it with your output of head(datetime), it works fine for me. But I think @RichScriven is right. By adding an entry without time I can reproduce your error...

Answer (score 2):

You can try `as.POSIX` and specify your format

```
as.POSIXlt(datetime, format=...)
```

or

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format=...)
```

Reproducible example

```
data <- data.frame(Date=as.Date("2017-01-01"), Time="01:01:01")
datetime <- paste(as.Date(data$Date), data$Time)

as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2017-01-01 01:01:00 CST"

data$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data
        # Date     Time            Datetime
# 1 2017-01-01 01:01:01 2017-01-01 01:01:01
```

As pointed out in comments, if you have datetimes with different formats, as.POSIX will return NA if you specify the format

```
data <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02")), Time=c("01:01:01", "01:01"))

        # Date     Time
# 1 2017-01-01 01:01:01
# 2 2017-01-02    01:01

datetime <- paste(as.Date(data$Date), data$Time)
data$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data

        # Date     Time            Datetime
# 1 2017-01-01 01:01:01 2017-01-01 01:01:01
# 2 2017-01-02    01:01                <NA>
```

**Solution**
You can obtain real Dates with `lubridate::ymd_hms` and argument `truncated`

```
library(lubridate)
data$Datetime <- ymd_hms(datetime, truncated=2)
data

        # Date     Time            Datetime
# 1 2017-01-01 01:01:01 2017-01-01 01:01:01
# 2 2017-01-02    01:01 2017-01-02 01:01:00
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work either....

Answer (score 2):

To return the time values properly, all values must contain a time (unless you use `format` as shown later).  In your example, it must be that one or more of your values does not contain a time.  Here is a simple example:

```
## with time - works as intended
as.POSIXct("2006-01-01 01:12:36")
# [1] "2006-01-01 01:12:36 PST"

## one value with time, one without - drops time element
as.POSIXct(c("2006-01-01 01:12:36", "2006-01-01"))
# [1] "2006-01-01 PST" "2006-01-01 PST"
```

Notice how the time was dropped from the second result, even though I used `as.POSIXct()`.  Make sure all the values in your `Time` column contain meaningful times.

You could use a character vector in the `format` argument as well, but that can be tedious for long vectors.  Note that a time is added to the second element here:

```
as.POSIXct(
    c("2006-01-01 01:12:36", "2006-01-01"), 
    format = c("%Y-%m-%d %T", "%Y-%m-%d")
)
# [1] "2006-01-01 01:12:36 PST" "2006-01-01 00:00:00 PST"
```

I would just make sure you have a valid time in the `Time` column before you `paste()`.

Comment: I tried [which(!grepl("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$", datetime))] in R, it shows that "integer(0)" I think all of the datetime are in %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S format.... So is there any possibility of this problem??? Thanks so much